# Duvida simples em relacao a vetores

Tags: c#, array, vector

1. Faça um programa que leia o valor dos elementos de um vetor de inteiros com 10 posições. Depois que os dados forem fornecidos o programa deverá:

a.    Mostrar o maior e o menor valor do vetor

b.    Mostrar quantos números pares e quantos números ímpares existem no vetor

c.    Mostrar a média aritmética dos valores do vetor

A resposta a que cheguei foi essa, mas não consigo rodar o programa por erro de sintaxe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace WorkBJA
{
    // Vetor de inteiros com 10 posições.
    //     a. Mostrar o maior e o menor valor do vetor
    //     b. Mostrar quantos números pares e quantos números ímpares existem no 
vetor
    //     c. Mostrar a média aritmética dos valores do vetor
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] Vetor = new int[10];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Elemento {i + 1} do Vetor: ");
                Vetor[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            
            Console.WriteLine($"O Maior Valor do Vetor é {AchaMaior(Vetor)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"O Menor Valor do Vetor é {AchaMenor(Vetor)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Existem {ContaPares(Vetor)} elementos Pares no 
Vetor");
            Console.WriteLine($"Existem {ContaÍmpares(Vetor)} elementos Ímpares no 
Vetor");
            Console.WriteLine($"A Média Aritmética dos elementos do vetor é 
{AchaMédia(Vetor):F2}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int AchaMaior(int[] V)
        {
            int Maior=V[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < V.Length; i++)
            {
                if (V[i] > Maior)
                    Maior = V[i];
            }
            return Maior;
        }
        static int AchaMenor(int[] V)
        {
            int Menor = V[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < V.Length; i++)
            {
                if (V[i] < Menor)
                    Menor = V[i];
            }
            return Menor;
        }
        static int ContaPares(int[] V)
        {
            int Pares = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < V.Length; i++)
            {
                if (V[i] % 2 == 0)
                    Pares++;
            }
            return Pares;
        }
        static int ContaÍmpares(int[] V)
        {
            int Ímpares = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < V.Length; i++)
            {
                if (V[i] % 2 != 0)
                    Ímpares++;
            }
            return Ímpares;
        }
        static double AchaMédia(int[] V)
        {
            int Soma=0;
            double Média;
            for (int i = 0; i < V.Length; i++)
            {
                Soma += V[i];
            }
            return (double)Soma / V.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o erro que está ocorrendo para que possamos te ajudar

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Lembrando que o [pt.so] é um site de perguntas e respostas e se não houver uma pergunta pontuando uma dúvida concreta a sua questão não poderá ser catalogada e portanto será fechada. Veja [ask], [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Não utilize acentos em suas variáveis como em Ímpares e também na hora de dar o `ConsoleWriteline()`, utilize o + para concatenar sua string.

Exemplo:

```
ConsoleWriteline("O Maior Valor do Vetor é " + AchaMaior(Vetor));
```